# Solve the equation $6\cos^4 y+\sin^2 y =5$

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the equation $$6\cos^4 y+\sin^2 y =5 \qquad (0\leq y \leq 360^\circ).$$

I used quadratics and got the answers $y= 18.0, 162.0, 198.0,$ and $342.0$ degrees, but it differs from the answer given which is $y= 45, 135, 225, 315 $ degrees. I am not sure how to solve this problem, thus any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please add your solution to the question so someone can spot the error.

Comment: Let $u=\sin^2y$, then $\cos^4y=(1-u)^2$, so you get a quadratic in $u$.

Comment: If y= 45 degrees then both sin(y) and cos(y) are equal to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ so that $6 cos^2(y)+ sin^2(y)= 6(1/2)+ 1/2= 7/2$, not 5 so the "given" answers cannot be correct!

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are correct. None of given answers: $45^\circ,135^\circ,225^\circ,315^\circ$ satisfies given equation.
$$6\cos^4y+\sin^2y=5$$
$$6\cos^4y-\cos^2y-4=0$$
$$\cos^2y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{97}}{12}$$

$$\cos y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{97}}{12}}$$
$$y=\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{97}}{12}}\approx 18.04^\circ, 180^\circ-\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{97}}{12}}\approx 161.96^\circ,$$$$ 180^\circ+\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{97}}{12}}\approx 198.04^\circ, \quad 360^\circ-\cos^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{97}}{12}}\approx 341.96^\circ$$

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you substitute $x=\cos^2(\text{y})$ we get:

$$6x^2-x-4=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{97}}{12}\tag1$$

Comment: The minus-sign must be excluded becauce $x$ is a square.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Anna You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$5=6\cos^4y+1-\cos^2y\iff6\cos^4y-\cos^2y-4=0$$

$$\cos^2y=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+24\cdot4}}{12}=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{97}}{12}\text{ or }\dfrac{1-\sqrt{97}}{12}<0$$

$$\implies\cos2y=\cdots=\dfrac{\sqrt{97}-5}6$$

Comment: Your formula for $\cos^2y$ is wrong.

Comment: @PaulFrost, Which formula you are referring to?

Comment: $\cos^2y=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+24}}{12}$. You have to replace $24$ by $96$.

Comment: @PaulFrost, Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Thank you for the help!